# java https client doesn't send cookies when domain is simple name

Tags: java, cookies, client

I have the following code.

```
  public void setCookie(String asCookie) {
    host = applicationURL.getHost();
    if ((host != null) && (asCookie != null)) {
      HttpCookie tCookie = new HttpCookie(COOKIE_NAME, asCookie);
      tCookie.setDomain(host);
      tCookie.setSecure(true);
      tCookie.setPath("/");
      tCookie.setVersion(0);
      try {
        URI basicCookie = new URI(PREFERRED_PROTOCOL, host, "/");
        cookieJar.add(basicCookie, tCookie);
      } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR:SessionID.setCookie:invalid host: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("ERROR:SessionID.setCookie: host or cookie is empty!");
    }
  }
```

When the host is

- 10.100.20.5 - it is working
- `gigi.kent` - it is working
- `gigi` it is NOT working

NOTE: `gigi` and `gigi.kent` and in /etc/hosts file and point to the ip address above

I am running with openjdk 1.8.0.282 under Windows.

I suspect there's a problem with domains with no dot but I really have a hard time figuring this one out, especially if it works with the previous one.

I've traced the header with mod_log_forensic in apache and the case where it is not working I don't get any cookie.

working

> HTTP/1.1|connection:close|Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded|Cache-Control:no-cache|Pragma:no-cache|User-Agent:Java/1.8.0_282|Host:gigi.kent|Accept:text/html,
> image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*;
> q=.2|Content-Length:20|Cookie:SESSION=5rnYovJ@ibNplzsD1P8

not working

> HTTP/1.1|connection:close|Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded|Cache-Control:no-cache|Pragma:no-cache|User-Agent:Java/1.8.0_282|Host:gigi|Accept:text/html,
> image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2|Content-Length:61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact in the way the URI was created. Using the original URL received from the application in the form of https://gigi/do/some/stuff and obtaining the URI it via toURI() was the solution.

Here is the diff below.

```
       try {
-        URI basicCookie = new URI(PREFERRED_PROTOCOL, host, "/");
+        URI basicCookie = applicationURL.toURI();
         cookieJar.add(basicCookie, tCookie);
```

So the final code is like below:

```
  try {
    URI basicCookie = applicationURL.toURI();
    cookieJar.add(basicCookie, tCookie);
  } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
```